# Python Skipping 'for' loop

Tags: python

I'm making a program that searches a file for code snippets. However, in my search procedure, it skips the for loop entirely (inside the search_file procedure). I have looked through my code and have been unable to find a reason. Python seems to just skip all of the code inside the for loop.

```
import linecache

def load_file(name,mode,dest):
    try:
        f = open(name,mode)
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        dest = open(name,mode)

def search_file(f,title,keyword,dest):
    found_dots = False

    dest.append("")
    dest.append("")
    dest.append("")

    print "hi"

    for line in f:
        print line
        if line == "..":            
            if found_dots:
                print "Done!"
                found_dots = False
            else:
                print "Found dots!"
                found_dots = True    
        elif found_dots:
            if line[0:5] == "title=" and line [6:] == title:
                dest[0] = line[6:]
            elif line[0:5] == "keywd=" and line [6:] == keyword:
                dest[1] = line[6:]
            else:
                dest[2] += line

f = ""
load_file("snippets.txt",'r',f)
search = []
search_file(f,"Open File","file",search)
print search
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, arguments are not passed by reference. That is, if you pass in an argument and the function changes *that argument* (not to be confused with data *of* that argument), the variable passed in *will not* be changed.

You're giving `load_file` an empty string, and that argument is referenced within the function as `dest`. You do assign `dest`, but that just assigns the local variable; it does not change `f`. If you want `load_file` to return something, you'll have to explicitly `return` it.

Since `f` was never changed from an empty string, an empty string is passed to `search_file`. Looping over a string will loop over the characters, but there are no characters in an empty string, so it does not execute the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside each function add `global f` then `f` would be treated as a global variable. You don't have to pass `f` into the functions either.